# Using if statement to determine if a Firebase User can access certain React Router paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got a React web app with routes defined via React Router.

The auth on the app is done with Firebase, and I want to protect certain routes depending upon whether a user is logged in or not.

To determine if the user is logged in, I have used the following function:

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {

    } else {

    }
  }
```

From there, I figured that I could put 'protected' routes in to the initial if as that would determine whether the user was logged in, like so:

```
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      <div>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
      </div>

    } else {
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    }
  }
```

If the user isn't logged in, then they'd be re-directed to the sign in component.

This however isn't working. The dashboard page just comes back as a blank white screen instead of redirecting.

Indeed, an error message is displayed in the console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Switch`, expected a ReactNode.

For reference, here is my full component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.userLoggedIn = this.userLoggedIn.bind(this)
    
  }


  userLoggedIn = () => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      <div>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
      </div>
    } else {
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <Switch>

      {this.userLoggedIn}

      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage}  />
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />

      </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I know the logic is flawed, but is there a way I could refactor my code to implement this really straightforward hack to get protected routes using Firebase Auth?

Hope that's clear, let me know if any more info is needed.

EDIT: Edited my code in line with answer, but now receiving the following error message:

```
TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured
PrivateRoute
src/PrivateRoute.js:8
   5 | import { AuthContext } from './Auth'
   6 | 
   7 | export default function PrivateRoute({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) {
>  8 |     const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
   9 |     return (
  10 |         <Route
  11 |         {...rest}
```

My updated code...

Auth.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';


export const AuthContext  = React.createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const  [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{currentUser}}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './Auth'

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext)
    return (
        <Route
        {...rest}
        render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
            <RouteComponent {...routeProps} currentUser={currentUser} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={'/signin'}/>
        )
        }
        />
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <Switch>

      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage}  />
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />

      </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

there are 2 ways of fixing this and cleaning it up a little.

Let's say you want only authenticated users to access the dashboard page

**The Easy Option:**

```
class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
    currentUser: undefined
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    this.setState({currentUser: user})
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <Switch>

      <Route exact path="/dashboard">
        {this.state.user ? (
          <Dashboard />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )}
      </Route>

      </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**A couple of notes:**

- It's best to get the current user and setting any initial state when the component mounts using `componentDidMount()`.
- Instead of using the constructor React supports simply just declaring initial state as I have
- Lastly, react-router has a `<Redirect to={path}/>` component, which is great for use cases such as checking for an authenticated user.

**The Cleaner (and my preferred option):**

If you want to abstract the authentication process and make your life simpler in the long term you can create 2 files (e.g. `base.js`, `Auth.js` and `PrivateRoute.js`)

- `base.js`is where we are going to initialise firebase

  ```
  import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

    const app = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
        databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
    });

    export default app;
  ```

**Notes:**

- I have put `process.env......` as the values for the API keys as it's always best practice to keep your keys in a `.env` file.
- `Auth.js` is where we are going to be handling getting the authenticated user when the authenticated state changes

**Auth.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import app from './base'

export const AuthContext  = React.createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const  [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{currentUser}}
        > 
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Notes:**

- **Don't forget to import React, useState, useEffect and firebase**
- This file will provide an authentication context so that you can grab it from anywhere in your React App

**PrivateRoute.js:**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './Auth'

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) {
    const currentUser = useContext(AuthContext)
    return (
        <Route
        {...rest}
        render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
            <RouteComponent {...routeProps} currentUser={currentUser} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={'/login'}/>
        )
        }
        />
    )
}
```

**Notes:**

- Over here we are importing the authentication context from the `Auth.js` file and getting the current user.
- We are then creating a `PrivateRoute`, which checks if there is a current user and if so using `Route` and `Redirect` from the `react-router-dom` package we can redirect a user to the `/login` page if they are not authenticated or to the `RouteComponent` that is passed along with additional props (if there are any).
- We are also passing along the `currentUser` in the `RouteComponent` as props so it's available in that component.

With this, you can now use the `PrivateRoute` component like this to make sure only authenticated users can use a given component:

```
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard"

<PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Comment: This is a great answer. So the final code snippet is what would be in my app.js (That’s where my current routes are, and assuming I went down the context route)? Would the rest of my links all remain the same? Like how my login/register etc are?

Comment: Exactly, So you would use `PrivateRoute` just like `Route` (as in how you indicate the path and declare the component to render) for components you want to be authenticated and the normal `Route` from 'react-router-dom' for components you want to be accessible by everyone.

Comment: Thanks again for the response! I've tried implementing the code... And unfortunately I'm getting this error: TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured. I'll update my original question, but would you be able to help?

Comment: Sure, did you import the useContext hook like this:  `import React, { useContext } from 'react';` ?

Comment: Yep! I'll update my code to show what I've done! :-)

Comment: Thanks! Would be great if you could also pop in the Auth.js file so I can see what's happening

Comment: Something is going wrong with the Auth process. I think it's cause you have missed a step. You are importing firebase all over the place but I don't think you have initialized it. You should only need to import it once.  Let me update the answer and add the step you are missing.

Comment: I have updated the code and added a `base.js` file where you should be importing and initialising firebase. Outside of this file, you shouldn't need to import it.

Comment: Thank you again for the response! Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error in my PrivateRoute.js file. I've tried googling the error to see the destructuring, and how to change it, but don't feel I understand enough about it. Although I am keen to use this solution as it's a lot cleaner than my idea.

Comment: Try just simply assigning currentUser directly instead of destrcutring like this `const  currentUser  = useContext(AuthContext)`

Comment: This is closer, no more errors! However... Even when signed in, I can't access my private routes now.. I'm really sorry for this, appreciate your help. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223784/discussion-between-faris-aziz-and-jon-nicholson).

Answer (score 2):

`this.userLoggedIn` is a function, and as such it must *return* the JSX you want it to render:

```
  userLoggedIn = () => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      return (<div>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
      </div>);
    } else {
      return <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />;
    }
  }
```

Also in your render function, you want to *call* the function `this.userLoggedIn`, not just drop it in as a value. Otherwise it won't do anything:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <Switch>

      {this.userLoggedIn()}

      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage}  />
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />

      </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
```